# Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Question 1.

Is there any notion of integration wrt a measurable function $g(x)$ like $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dg(x)$ If yes, how it is defined?
I know how it is defined in Riemann-Stieltjes sense if $g(x)$ is monotone increasing function. But what is the meaning of this integral if $g(x) $ is only a measurable function.

Question 2.

Does there exist any version of Riesz representation theorem which gurrantees the existence of a measurable function $ g(x)$ such that the functional is $=\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dg(x)$. Here the integral is in Riemann stieltjes sense. Would like to get the actual statement of this version.

Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration). As far as I know there is no theory for arbitrary measurable $g$

Comment: You might take a look at the dual spaces of $L^p$...